# Design a XOR gate and a XNOR gate using a 2 to 4 Demultiplexer and 2-input OR gates

Tags: hardware, xor, digital-logic, nor

As above, can you please include a diagram or an image and explain me the reason of this design? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [2 to 4 Demultiplexer](http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/combinational/decoder_demux_four.html) routes one input `IN` to one of four outputs (`OUT0`, `OUT1`, `OUT2`, `OUT3`).

[image]
(picture from http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/combinational/decoder_demux_four.html)

The selection of the active output is done via two selection inputs `A` and `B`.

To implement a two-input `XOR`, you can set the multiplexer data input to constant `1`. Then feed `OUT1` and `OUT2` to a two-input `OR`. `OUT1` and `OUT2` are active, if the selection inputs are different (one input `0` and one input `1`).

For a two-input `XNOR`, outputs `OUT0` and `OUT3` are fed to the `OR` gate. Outputs `OUT0` and `OUT3` are active if both selection inputs are equal (both `0` or both `1`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and I got it.  I have another minor question, are you sure that we do not need to use all 4 outputs and generate XOR and XNOR? I mean, what happens to the other 2 outputs that are not used, where are they going to be connected?

Comment: Yes, I am. It is no problem to leave outputs unconnected. You only have to make sure that all inputs have a defined state. Therefore, open inputs are not really save for all technologies.